# How to remove carriage returns in the middle of a line

Tags: perl, file, special-characters

I have file that is read by application in Unix and Windows. However, I am encountering problems when reading in Windows with ^M in the middle of the data. I am only wanting to remove the ^M in the middle of the lines such as field 4 and field 5.

I have tried using `perl -pe 's/\cM\cJ?//g'`, but it removes everything into one line which i don't want. I want the data to stay in the same line but remove the extra ones

```
# Comment^M
# field1_header|field2_header|field3_header|field4_header|field5_header|field6_header^M
#^M
field1|field2|field3|fie^Mld4|fiel^Md5|field6^M
^M
```

Answer (score 1):

To just remove CR in the middle of a line:

```
perl -pe 's/\r(?!\n)//g'
```

You can also write this `perl -pe 's/\cM(?!\cJ)//g'`. The `?!` construct is a [negative look-ahead expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f!pattern%29). The pattern matches a CR, but only when it is not followed by a LF.

Of course, if producing a file with unix newlines is acceptable, you can simply strip all CR characters:

```
perl -pe 'tr/\015//d'
```

What you wrote, `s/\cM\cJ?//g`, strips a CR and the LF after it if there is one, because the LF is part of the matched pattern.

Comment: Don't use octal, much too confusing and error prone ... which you prove yourself by using `\010` instead of `\012`.  Use `\r` and `\n`, much clearer.

Comment: @mscha: `\n` and company are subtly different: they mean “whatever is CR on this platform”, not a particular byte value. This is admittedly mostly theoretical, since `\r` is ASCII CR and `\n` is ASCII LF on both Windows and unix, and other platforms are highly marginal.

Comment: On Windows a "\n" is "\015\012"
On Unix/Linux a "\n" is "\012"

You should change your post and remove "\n".

Comment: @Sid: No, `\n` is just `\012` on Windows. (Try `print unpack("H*", "\n")`.) What happens on a Windows perl is that *when reading or writing a file* that's opened as text (such as STDIN/STDOUT), a CRLF (`\015\012`) newline is converted from/to `\012`. So on a Windows perl, `-pe 'tr/\r//d'` and `-pe 's/\r(?!\n)//g'` have the same effect (they wouldn't if the file had been opened in binary mode).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easiest solution might be to check your filetype before moving between Unix and Windows. [dos2unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) and [unix2dos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) might be what you really need, instead of a regex.

I'm not sure what character `^M` is supposed to be, but carriage return is `\015` or `\r`. So, `s/\r//g` should suffice. Remember it also removes your last carriage return, if that is something you wish to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $a = "field1|field2|field3|fie^Mld4|fiel^Md5|field6^M";

$a =~ s/\^M(?!$)//g;

print $a;
```

Comment: Did you try your code and look at the output?  It's removing the character after the ^M too.

Comment: @ysth - you were right, thx. I edited the response now and put a negative lookahead for the end of line (its removing only ^M that is not followed by an EOL)